# responsive flag element css only

Tags: html, css

I want to create a flag-shaped element using only CSS. I want this element to be responsive, i.e. I want it to grow/shrink in width as it's parent div grows/shrinks with the page.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="flag">Example text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 25%;
}
.flag {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 10px 40px 10px;
  position: relative; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: blue;
}
.flag:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 25px solid white;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

I've tried changing border-left and border-right to be 50%. That doesn't work. And I can't use vw-units on this project.

I can do it with Javascript. But I need to be able to do it solely with CSS.

Comment: This doesn't use only CSS3, but if you are willing to use that, then you must be dealing with browsers that can support SVG. SVG will scale to anything. Just a thought.

Comment: Define “flag-shaped”. And note that “responsive” normally means something that *changes layout* according to viewport dimensions.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the way your code works now?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3, you may try using **@media** query to do it:

You can either place all the media queries in the same file:

//example one

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    // if browser width >= 1200px, fall into these lines:
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    // if browser width is between 768px ~ 979px, fall into these lines:    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    // if browser width <= 768px, fall into these lines:
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    // if browser width <= 480px, fall into these lines:
}
```

Or you can break them into separate files

//example two

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But I'm looking for something that will respond smoothly to changes in window width.